# How to configure postfix + dovecot to copy and forward?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have configured postfix + dovecot as per [this guide](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrzg7nzfs9xy6s6/How%20to%20configure%20PostFix%20and%20Dovecot%20for%20Virtual%20Users%20with%20out%20a%20Database.docx?dl=1), originally published at http://neranjara.org/article/title/How_to_configure_PostFix_and_Dovecot_for_Virtual_Users_with_out_a_Database_ now defunct. I used virtual users option. Everything works great.

Now I'd like to configure a specific email address to forward all emails to another address but to retain a copy of email in the original mailbox.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) to have mails to some recipients cloned and sent via BCC to another email address.

Comment: This works, thank you. A follow-up question, though. I have this in my main.cf "virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox" and then "@domain.com domain.com/catchall/" in my vmailbox. This catchall destination can't be forwarded using the recipient_bcc_maps method. Is there any way I got these forwarded too?

Comment: Sure, that's completely possible. Just write `@example.com` in the table referred in `recipient_bcc_maps` instead of a complete email address. Also see the documentation for `recipient_bcc_maps`.

Comment: But won't this forward *all* emails, not catch all only?

Comment: It will send a copy of all emails to `*@example.com` to the recipient you've configured.

Comment: Yeah, this is not exactly what I want. Let's assume I have bob@example.com, john@example.com and jim@example.com. I don't want *their* email to be forwarded. I only want to forward emails that end up in catchall@example.com, which is all email sent to the domain but that doesn't match any of existing addresses. I don't want to repeat all the existing addresses in recipient_bcc_map to avoid duplication of information.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Use the `always_bcc` setting in Postfix main.cf (see http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).</s>

Either use joschis version or create some type of alias.

Alias originalname@example.org => user1@example.org, user@example.org

Comment: This going to forward email for *all* email address isn't it? Or am I reading this wrong? I need to forward mail from one particular address only.

Comment: You're right, I skipped the word "specific". Modified my answer.